# Sequences of sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $a_n>0$,$b_n>1$ and
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=0,  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=1$$
Define
$$A_n=\{x:a_n\leq x < b_n\}.$$
Find $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}A_n$.
I don’t know how to approach  this problem. Are sets in $A_n$ are monotone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try the $\liminf$ one: By your hypothesis, for each $\epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
0 < a_n < \epsilon \text{ and } 1 < b_n < 1+\epsilon
$$
Hence,
$$
[\epsilon, 1] \subset A_n \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
$$
\Rightarrow [\epsilon,1] \subset \cap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n
$$
$$
\Rightarrow [\epsilon,1] \subset \liminf A_n
$$
This is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, so
$$
(0,1] \subset \liminf A_n
$$
Now if $x \leq 0$, then $x\notin A_n$ for all $n$ and so $x\notin \liminf A_n$. Also, if $x > 1$, then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
b_n < x \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x \notin A_n \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x\notin \cap_{n=m}^{\infty} A_n \quad\forall m\in \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x\notin \liminf A_n
$$
and hence $\liminf A_n = (0,1]$.

Perhaps you can try something similar for $\limsup$ and ask if you get stuck. Hope this helps.

Comment: I  understand your solution for lim inf but I am still having trouble with the limsup @PrahladVaidyanathan

Comment: Is the limsup (0,1+epslion)?